# Passing variable as argument for exec.Command()

Tags: go, arguments

I want to read user input and use it as an argument for a command. I got this code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter img path: ")
    imgPath, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    args := []string{imgPath, "stdout", "-l spa+eng"}
    out, err := exec.Command("tesseract", args...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

But when I execute it it outputs an error saying **exit status 1**.

If instead of using the variable **imgPath** as an argument I write some text directly into the array it works like a charm.

Comment: 1. Don't ignore the error. Really. Don't. 2. Debug what really is in imgPath. 3. `"-l spa+eng"` probably should be **two** arguments.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. As I say in the question if I write args := []string{"asdf.png", "stdout", "-l spa+eng"} it works as it is supposed to.

Comment: Then concentrate on points 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code returns a line **with the delimiter** (I work on Windows and its EOL is '\r\n'), something that wasn't shown when I printed it on the console.

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
imgPath, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

In my case it ended up working after I trimmed  '\r\n' from the input:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter img path: ")
    imgPath, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    imgPath= strings.TrimRight(line, "\r\n")

    args := []string{imgPath, "stdout", "-l spa+eng"}
    out, err := exec.Command("tesseract", args...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```